# display links in one line on the image

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want to display multiple links on the image. the located on top right but all of the links are put on each other. I want them to be separated in one line. I used display:inline. but it doesn't work.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
    display:inline;

}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Text</h2>
<p>How to place text over an image:</p>

<div class="container">
  <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="top-right">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="top-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="top-right">Centered</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either use  clear:both or overflow:hidden in your styling tag for the same.